# Trying to install Ubuntu on an old pc to be used as a server, having issues

Tags: boot

I've picked up an old computer my grandma used to have, and put another hard drive in it so I can use it as a media server. I wanted to install Ubuntu because I'm just following a tutorial, but I've run into an issue which I believe is being caused by the bios. Before I even installed Ubuntu, I had issues. The computer would boot, get past the splash screen, then ask my keyboard layout. As soon as I used the keyboard, the computer froze. So I tried entering bios from the splash screen. Same result, freezing as soon as I touch the keyboard. I put Ubuntu on a flash drive and started the installation. The first time, I pressed enter on the keyboard to select, and to no surprise, a freeze happened. So next time I waited out the 30 seconds and the installation went fine, went into the live environment, etc. I got Ubuntu installed on both of the drives just in case. When I restart the computer, a screen saying this comes up and I can't do anything, even after another restart.

"Reboot and select proper boot device"

"Or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

I can't get any further than this, I suspect it must be a corrupted bios/bios error, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Computer is an HP Pavilion p6803w, running an Athlon II X2 Dual Core 220 with 4gb of ram, which meets the requirements of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, which I'm trying to install.

Edit 2: I've tried installing both Xubuntu and Ubuntu server, and neither worked.

Comment: You've provided few specific details, with no real details on your PC (*mine is a 2008 dell? do you consider that old?*), what specs your machine has (*does it meet the requirements for the Ubuntu product you're trying to install*), nor what Ubuntu product you're trying to install?  You also didn't tell us if you verified ISO after download as per instructions, or media validation was done (*this varies on product/release details we weren't given*).

Comment: I suggest that you start over. It would be wise to [verify your download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu). Then, follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) and do not deviate from the official instructions. As a prerequisite, unrelated to Ubuntu, you will need to know how to boot a USB from your BIOS. If you aren't sure how to do this, you'll need to consult with your motherboard documentation.  Unfortunately we can not assist with BIOS issues or other hardware problems.

Comment: From all the issue you describe I would say the computer is broken. Yes you finally got it installed but it does not work. Installing on both drives, why? You have not specified the most basic info, Hardware specs and version of Ubuntu you are trying to use.

Comment: Those Athlon II machines had very weak video subsystems. If you're installing Ubuntu Desktop 22.04, then you're likely pushing the video hardware too hard. A less-demanding version of Ubuntu, such as Xubuntu, may work for you. That said, if this is intended to be a server, you could use Ubuntu Server 22.04, which does not use a GUI, and can run on quite a bit of older hardware if you're patient enough.

Comment: I don't see any specs provided that verify the requirements are met for Ubuntu Desktop (3D accelerated card with 256MB minimum RAM etc) as Ubuntu Desktop has minimums on the video card as well (having done so since 17.10) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements.  The lowest requirements exist for Ubuntu Server, and as you want to use it as a server system, why use a desktop system (esp. medium-high resource one)

Comment: Since the machine is so old, something like Antix may work for you https://antixlinux.com/

Comment: `I've tried installing both Xubuntu and Ubuntu server, and neither worked.` - What did not work?

Comment: I still don't see any video hardware specs being offered; Xubuntu it's the *lightest* flavor offered; though if your issue relates to video card details you've not provided, I doubt Lubuntu would install either. Xubuntu has near the same video requirements of Ubuntu Desktop and you've not said if they were met  (*yes in testing I've had great success with Xubuntu on hardware as old as 2005 with current releases, but I always consider details I've mentioned numerous times you've not provided*)